# Xml declaration for deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, serializable

Among other data, I have the following XML being sent to me:

```
<jx:Agency xsi:type="nc:OrganizationType1">
    <nc:OrganizationAbbreviationText>ABC</nc:OrganizationAbbreviationText>
</jx:Agency>
```

In my code, I have Agency declared as follows (I also have the class Agency with a single XmlAttribute OrganizationAbbreviationText):

```
[XmlElement("Agency", Namespace = jx)]
public Agency Agency { get; set; }
```

But when I attempt to deserialize, I get "The specified type was not recognized: name='OrganizationType1'" along with the namespace=url

Does anyone know how to properly describe the Agency in my structure?

I am not serializing the structure... the file is being sent to me and I'm deserializing it using the following:

```
Document doc;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pathName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));
    doc = (Document)ser.Deserialize(fs);
    fs.Close();
}
```

This is why the xml file needs to be described properly in the Document class.

mho, Here's the code for the Agency class:

```
[XmlElement(Namespace = jx)]
public class Agency
{
    [XmlAttribute("OrganizationAbbreviationText", Namespace = nc)]
    public string OrganizationAbbreviationText { get; set; }
}
```

I don't believe OrganizationType1 really comes into play except that I cannot de-serialize the file I'm being sent without addressing it.  jx and nc are constant strings containging URLs.  I very much appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: What serializer are you using ?

Comment: XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));

Comment: Post your serialization code please. You shouldn't be having this issue unless you are specifically trying to read that attribute.

Comment: Robotsushi, I edited the post to include de-serialization code.

Comment: The problem is, XmlSerializer is trying find type that corresponds to "nc:OrganizationType1" and is not able to find it.

OrganizationType1 is typically a sub-class of Agency with XmlType attribute set to nc:OrganizationType1. In addition Agency class should have a XmlInclude attribute indicating exisitence of OrganizationType1.

Comment: can you paste your agency class (and OrganizationType1 if any) so we could help you better

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, you're missing a type that corresponds to `nc:OrganizationType1`. In this case you can simply reuse `Agency` class for `nc:OrganizationType1` (if `Agency` is either default type or `nc:OrganizationType1` only).

Also `OrganizationAbbreviationText` in Agency is an `XmlElement` and not `XmlAttribute`.

I have simplified your case and created a sample code that works. Please note     `[XmlType(TypeName = "OrganizationType1", Namespace = "some-name-space")]` on the top of `Agency` class. Hope it helps, happy to explain

```
[XmlRoot("Agency")]
[XmlType(TypeName = "OrganizationType1", Namespace = "some-name-space")] 
public class Agency 
{
    [XmlElement("OrganizationAbbreviationText", Namespace = "some-name-space")]    
    public string OrganizationAbbreviationText { get; set; } 
} 

public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        string xml = "<Agency xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"" 
                    + " xmlns:nc=\"some-name-space\" xsi:type=\"nc:OrganizationType1\">"
                            + "<nc:OrganizationAbbreviationText>ABC</nc:OrganizationAbbreviationText>"
                    + "</Agency>";

        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml)) 
        {     
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Agency));
            var agency = (Agency)ser.Deserialize(reader);
            Console.WriteLine(agency.OrganizationAbbreviationText);
        } 
    }

}
```